# Install and use Net_UserAgent_Detect via PEAR

Tags: php, pear, package-managers

I would like to make use of the class

```
Net_UserAgent_Detect
```

So I installed Net_UserAgent_Detect via pear

```
pear install Net_UserAgent_Detect
```

I found that the respective files have been installed under /usr/share/php. But when I run my php script I still get the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Net_UserAgent_Detect' not found in ...
```

Do I need to include a file from "Net_UserAgent_Detect" separately ? So should I mention it in php.ini or ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you use the corresponding file include() in your script?

Comment: No I did not, I was not sure if I was supposed to or not. Thought that automatically includes "pear" installed files. Figured I should've thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/0/) compatible autoloader when you have your [include path setup](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.includepath) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself.

After "pear" installing a package, one must find that file and manually include it as well.